# automatically load project's environment to irb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, irb

Rails has useful command `rails console`, which downloads all necessary data and then we can interact with rails project in `irb`. Is there the same technique for Ruby project (built on Ruby language)? By this trick I can play with Ruby project in the `irb` without concerning about loading libraries, modules, classes, files and so on.
Thanks

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Your project should have one file which loads the environment. Assuming your project is in lib/project.rb then simply:

```
$ irb -Ilib -rproject
```

Answer (score 1):

From one of my projects:

```
# Creates an IRB console useful for debugging experiments
# Loads up the environment for the condition passed
def console
  File.open("./tmp/irb-setup.rb", 'w') do |f|
    f.puts "# Initializes the environment for IRb."
    f.puts "Code to initialize your project here"
    f.puts "$: << '#{File.expand_path(".")}/'"  #handle load path       
  end
  irb = RUBY_PLATFORM =~ /(:?mswin|mingw)/ ? 'irb.bat' : 'irb'
  # require your code
  libs =  " -r irb/completion"
  libs <<  " -r #{File.dirname(__FILE__) + "/base"}"
  libs << " -r ./tmp/irb-setup.rb" # require the config file you just wrote
  puts "Loading #{@options.env} environment..."
  exec "#{irb} #{libs} --simple-prompt"
end
```

The trick is that you construct the irb command to autorequire all the code you need. I also needed to set up some configuration so I add the magick of writing a file I then require in IRb.

Comment: Please explain where to put this function in the project and how to call it.

Comment: That kind of depends on how your project is organized. I have it a file that contains a commandline utility that does things like generators, servers, running the code etc. But if you put in a file `console.rb` and at the end simply add `console` then it should work when you run it with `ruby console.rb` it should work. You'll have to customize it to suite your needs, I've tried to indicate where.

Answer (score 0):

In my case my initialization script was in the current working directory. The below worked for me.

```
irb -r ./setup.rb
```

Answer (score 0):

For any project, you could also add a `.irbrc`, and require what you want in there, most likely the entry point of the project.

```rb
require "lib/project"
```